# Converting following curl command to axios

Tags: node.js, curl, axios

What is the axios equivalent for the following curl command?

```
curl -G https://octopart.com/api/v3/parts/match    
-d queries='[{"mpn":"SN74S74N"}]'    
-d apikey=KEY      
-d limit=0 
-d include[]=specs 
-d show[]=specs
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give axios the URL string and the query parameters as an object, as described in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you.

```
axios.post('https://octopart.com/api/v3/parts/match ',
 {queries: [{mpn:"SN74S74N"}], apikey: "KEY", limit: 0, include:["specs"], show: ["specs"]}
)
.then( response => {
     console.log("Response is: ", response);
})
.catch( error => {
     console.log("Error is :", error);
});
```